# React Native- Accurate shadows in Android

Tags: android, reactjs, svg, react-native

**Target Shadow:**

[image: Target Shadow]

**Current Implementation:**

[image: Current Implementation]

I am using React-Native-Shadow but it does not blur the shadow, as there is no blur implementation in React-Native-SVG.

Is there any way that that above shadow can be acheived? I even tried blurring the shaodow svg but was unsuccessful.

Even in android, there is no way to change color of elevation or any other library that provides accurate shadows. If anyone can suggest me a way, I can make my own module.

ShadowOpt Used:

```
  width: 105,
  height: 1,
  top: 0,
  color: '#0c00ff',
  border: 27,
  radius: 0,
  opacity: 0.8,
  x: 36,
  y: 30,
  style: { position: 'absolute' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use these to create a shadow, however I am not sure it will help on SVG. I haven't use them. Let me know

```
elevationLow: {
          ...Platform.select({
            ios: {
              shadowColor: '#000',
              shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
              shadowOpacity: 0.8,
              shadowRadius: 2,    
            },
            android: {
              elevation: 5,
            },
          }),
        },
```

See that you will have to import Platform from 'react-native' since the style has different implementations in iOS or Android.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but Elevation has no means to change color or even x scale. I would like to create colored shadow depicting the button to be translucent and light glowing down from it.

Comment: Ah,  thought you meant the shadow had a couple of blurry lines. So what is the thing you want to do? Blur the text? There is a library for that called react-native-blur. As far as I know, you can only blur an image natively.